# Automation issue on hideproxy.me

Tags: selenium, automation

Why I can not get text in page when I search on "https://us.hideproxy.me/"? My code run successfuly on google.com. Ok, no problem but same code run on this site, I can get only empty or null text. Code is devaloped with selenium 3.11 and using FirefoxDriver.
On https://us.hideproxy.me output:

```
>>>>>
>>>>>
>>>>>
>>>>>
>>>>>
>>>>>
>>>>>
>>>>>
>>>>>
>>>>>
```

Same code on google.com output:

```
>>>>>Спецтехника Caterpillar: дорожная, строительная техника CAT ...
>>>>>Customer Applications and Portals - Lifecycle Support | Solar Turbines
>>>>>Teknoxgroup: Home
>>>>>Caterpillar | Education
>>>>>Cat | Rental Power - Commercial and Industrial Generator Rental ...
>>>>>Caterpillar | Dealer Technician
>>>>>About Us | Solar Turbines
>>>>>Cat | Marine Product Support | Caterpillar
>>>>>Energy Power Systems | Caterpillar Generators & Cat Engines Australia
>>>>>Caterpillar | Financial Information www.cat.com/proxy
```

The Code:

```
driver.get("https://us.hideproxy.me/");
driver.findElement(By.className("url-input")).sendKeys("https://www.google.com/search?q=site:" + "cat.com");
driver.findElement(By.className("url-button")).click();
String resultText = "";
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='g']"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    resultText = resultText + ">>>>>" + element.getText() + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Update the question with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try (it’s for python. You can find same do line for other languages.) time.sleep(-some seconds-) line? Maybe before page load your code try to run itself.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the site protect pages... Keep simple and going on :)

Comment: It happens to everyone who now can do some good stuffs in selenium :) Don’t care this little jokes of selenium :)